# Simple batch file related to Steam

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

I'm trying to customise a bit, already made very basic batch file, made purely for fun, who's purpose is to change your Steam client statuses.

The original file is [here](https://github.com/p0lemarchus/steam-chat-status-switcher/blob/main/chat%20status%20toggle.bat), and it works just fine.

However, I wanted to use `if errorlevel`, instead of his `if '%choice%'=='`.

Obviously I can't make it work, and would appreciate it, if someone can assist me.

`if errorlevel` is way better, in my oppion, because instantly goes to your selected choice, also has cool **BEEP** sound every time you press unassigned key / make unavailable choice.

I tried like this, but it isn't working, batch file simply closes it self, and doesn't execute a task.

```bash
choice /c:12345678 /n > nul
if errorlevel 8 goto EXIT
if errorlevel 7 goto OFFLINE
if errorlevel 6 goto BUSY
if errorlevel 5 goto LOOKING TO PLAY
if errorlevel 4 goto LOOKING TO TRADE
if errorlevel 3 goto AWAY
if errorlevel 2 goto INVISIBLE
if errorlevel 1 goto ONLINE
```

Comment: What error message are you getting? Your example shows data entry and switching to 8 options, but it doesn't show any of the code you're supposed to be jumping to. Does your batch file have labels like `:EXIT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely elsewhere in your code, because this works as expected:

```
@echo off
choice /c:123 /n > nul
if errorlevel 3 goto EXIT
if errorlevel 2 goto OFFLINE
if errorlevel 1 goto BUSY
echo Someone hit Ctrl-break and continued
goto EXIT

:OFFLINE
echo OFFLINE
goto EXIT

:BUSY
echo BUSY
goto EXIT

:EXIT
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using labels with spaces, as anything after a space will be ignored, that means both `LOOKING TO PLAY` and `LOOKING TO TRADE` would try to locate and run the first encountered label beginning with `:LOOKING`.

I'd probably forget about using multiple labels, and would, on this occasion, choose not to use `If ErrorLevel`.

For Example:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "CMD=%SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe %SystemRoot%\System32\url.dll,FileProtocolHandler"

:Start
Set "Lbl=Start"
Set "Sta="
Set "URI=steam://friends/status/"
Echo(
Echo 1. Online
Echo 2. Invisible
Echo 3. Away
Echo 4. Looking To Trade
Echo 5. Looking To Play
Echo 6. Busy
Echo 7. Sign out from friends and chat
Echo 8. Exit from Steam
Echo(
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C 12345678 /M "Select your preferred status"
If %ErrorLevel% Equ 1 Set "Sta=online"
If %ErrorLevel% Equ 2 Set "Sta=invisible"
If %ErrorLevel% Equ 3 Set "Sta=away"
If %ErrorLevel% Equ 4 Set "Sta=trade"
If %ErrorLevel% Equ 5 Set "Sta=play"
If %ErrorLevel% Equ 6 Set "Sta=busy"
If %ErrorLevel% Equ 7 Set "Sta=offline"
If %ErrorLevel% Equ 8 (Set "URI=steam//ExitSteam" & Set "Lbl=:EOF")
%CMD% %URI%%Sta%
GoTo %Lbl%
```